# Running Embarrasingly Parallel operations on a single piece of data using Dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-delayed

I was following [this](https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html) tutorial and I was able to parallelize a for loop where operations were done independently on multiple files. However, now I need to perform an iterative function to extract variables into 300 files from a single xarray dataset (source). My functions looks like this :

```
def build_data(parameters)
    extract var1 from source
    extract var2 from source
    extract var3 from source
    ..........
    return('finished')
```

I have set 6 workers and to run this function in a loop 300 times, I implemented :

```
source = xr.opendataset()
build_delayed = []
for i in range (0,300):
   task = dask.delayed (build_data) (params)
   build_delayed.append(task)
dask.compute(*build_delayed)
```

But this is not working and seems like latency is building up as all workers are trying access same piece of data. Also, when the loop ends, `None` is returned in build_delayed[ ].

What am I missing here? How do I make it work in parallel in this case?

(My detailed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971626/parallelizing-generic-python-code-with-dask).)

EDIT : MVCE :

```
stations = []
for key in valid_stations:
    station = pd.read_csv('~/projects/LIS_verification/pyLISF/data/IFI-Observations/flow_2/'+key+'.csv')
    station.reset_index(drop = True,inplace=True)
    station.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
    station.index = pd.to_datetime(station.index)
    stations.append(station)

routedat = xr.opendataset('/LDAS/02-ILDAS/OUTPUT/EXP002/SURFACEMODEL/file1.nc')
    
def build_data(stations,routedat,i) :
    try :
        start_date = stations[i]['Streamflow (cumecs)'].first_valid_index()
        lis_date = routedat['time'].values
        return (start_date,lis_date)
    except Exception as e :
        return( start_date,str(e))
    
for i in range (0,10):
    task = dask.delayed (build_data) (stations,routedat,i)
    build_delayed.append(task)

dask.compute(*build_delayed)
```

I am getting the required output but the time taken is too large as compared to sequential loop (508 ms vs 31 seconds).

UPDATE : I was able to run it successfully in < 300 ms in parallel by using command `.compute(scheduler='synchronous')`

Comment: As mdurant suggested on the other question please try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) eventually with a toy example. Otherwise it's not clear what is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, yet did you try to create a reduce function and compute it?

Something like:

```
@dask.delayed
def delayed_reduce(array):
    out = ''
    for entry in array:
        print (entry)
        out = out + str(entry) + ' '
    return out

build_delayed = []
for i in range (0,300):
   task = dask.delayed (build_data) (params)
   build_delayed.append(task)
out = delayed_reduce(build_delayed) 
value = out.compute()
```

This is just skeleton of the code, yet you get the idea. If you want to debug what is going on, add a different return value and also print it to some file.

Also, you did not mention how you run dask. Are you using distributed? If you do, make sure you have initialized the workers and scheduler.

Hopefully this skeleton code will help you locate the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I am running dask on a HPC's login node. And yes, the workers are properly initialized as I have a successfull implementation of another parallel loop earlier in the script. Do you think that since all the workers are trying to access the same variable "source" at the same time, something is going wrong?

Comment: If you have things properly initialized, then the issue is in the code. usually there is one scheduler and one or more workers pointing to that scheduler and tasks are being sent to workers.  I really did not look closely at your code, yet it seems that you were missing a reduce step that forces all the computations you send to be computed. I am not sure how HPC login node works, yet if you have an example that work there,look for a line that looks like: `dask.distributed.Client(scheduler_link)` - this connects you dask. unless you setup the client another way, you will need this line.

Comment: Yes, you were right. My problems disappeared once I used .compute(scheduler='synchronous'). Thank you.

Comment: Great.  So just to be clear for everyone else who may have this problem. You did not have to add a reduce function, and the following line  `dask.compute(*build_delayed)` you had originally was sufficient? Your problem was that you did not define the proper scheduler - am I correct? If you verify this, I will edit my answer for others.